# JQuery Fetching the cell of the last row of a table and can we use autocomplete to hide some value in it

Tags: java, javascript, jquery

My first query,
 my code goes like this
suppose a table with 5 rows and id = "mytable" and 3 cells in it

```
$("#mytable tbody tr:last td").each(function(i, td){
    alert("value "+ "   "+i+"   "+td);
});
```

now alert results are 
i will iterate from 0 to 3 and td will be [object HTMLTableCellElement]

Now i want the value inside the td 
i tried td.html() but jquery says td.html() is not a function

My second query is regarding autocomplete

I have a non primary key autocomplete and on the basis of selection i have to fill in data.
Is there any way i can hide a primary key along with the autocomplete so that when user select from autocomplete a non primary key value, i can get the primary key hidden field and fetch other data regarding that value.
My code for this goes something like this

I have tried this code in this i'm putting the primary key inside the square brackets [] then splitting it and on basis of primary key m filling the data but is there any way i can hide the primary key totally. I mean like on mouse hover user will be displayed that part rather than inside autocomplete list.

```
e.g. abc [123]
     abc [345]
```

here abc is the actual autocomplete values n i want to hide the primary key part which distinguishes them rather than displaying them in square brackets.

```
 $("#myTextBox").autocomplete({source: myListItems,

            change : function(event, ui) {
                var value = $("#myTextBox").val();
                 var splitValues = value.split('[');
                 var last = splitValues[1].lastIndexOf(']');
                 var tail = splitValues[1].substring(0,last);
                 $("#myTextBox").val(splitValues[0]);
                populateOtherFields(response, tail);
            },
            select : function(event, ui) {
                var value = ui.item.value;
                 var splitValues = value.split('[');
                 var last = splitValues[1].lastIndexOf(']');
                 var tail = splitValues[1].substring(0,last);
                 $("#myTextBox").val(splitValues[0]);
                populateOtherFields(response, tail);
            }
     }); 
   function populateOtherFields(response, tail){
            // code for populating other fields
       }
```

One more thing i want to add is that on selecting the item from autocomplete it still displays the complete string with square brackets and only after hitting tab button it removes the square brackets value. Can anyone tell what am i missing or suggest any other way of doing it.
Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

to fetch cellof last row in table

```
// first count total tr
var i=$("#mytable tbody tr").length;

//then select last tr's all td
var lastRowTds=$("#mytable tbody tr").eq(i).('td');
```

Answer (score 1):

try something like this:

```
$('#mytable').find('tr:last td').each(function() {
    alert($(this).html()); 
});
```